# Returning the first row of a wordpress result set produces a parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently developing a photo blog using WordPress with a custom gallery plugin. I've created a function which works like a charm on my local machine. As soon as I put it on the production environment, I'm getting an error.

This is the function which produces the error:

```
function cz_get_photo($id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT title, filename FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "gallery WHERE photo_id = " . $id . " LIMIT 1;")[0];
}
```

I'm getting the following error code: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in (my-file-path)/functions.php on line 459"

Why does this work on my local machine but not on the server? I'm using the same WordPress version on both environments with the same plugins.

Comment: what is the PHP version u are in ?

Comment: On my local machine it is version 5.5.6. I currently have no access to the server, but I'm sure it's at least 5.3.

Comment: Yes the sytax is not supported in lower version i.e. adding [0] at the end. SO u may need to get the data first and then return the value.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've created a function which works like a charm on my local machine.
> As soon as I put it on the production environment, I'm getting an
> error.

#### The reason is your webserver must be running PHP version less than 5.4.

What you are trying to do is called *Function array dereferencing*.
That's a [new feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) of PHP 5.4

#### Rewrite your code like such that it works on your webserver PHP version ..

```
function cz_get_photo($id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $arr=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT title, filename FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "gallery WHERE photo_id = " . $id . " LIMIT 1;");
    return $arr[0];
}
```

Comment: Oh man, that must be the problem. I think the server is running version 5.3.x. I will test this as soon as I have access to the server. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
Please You are use this code
<?php
   global $wpdb;    
   function cz_get_photo($id)
   {
     $row =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT title, filename FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "gallery WHERE photo_id = " . $id . " LIMIT 1");
     return $row[0];
   }
?>
```